# Improving PostgreSQL FTS Query

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I am relatively new to Postgres full text search and still trying to understand it. I am working on ways I could optimize this query in PostgreSQL Full Text search. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT articles.article_id, article_title, article_excerpt, article_author, article_link_perm, article_default_image, article_date_added, article_bias_avg, article_rating_avg, article_keywords, 
ts_rank(search_vector, to_tsquery('snowden|obama|nsa'))  AS rank
FROM development.articles
WHERE search_vector @@ to_tsquery('english', 'snowden|obama|nsa') AND ts_rank(search_vector, to_tsquery('snowden|obama|nsa'))  > .045 ORDER BY article_date_added DESC, rank DESC LIMIT  20
```

And EXPLAN ANAYLIZE looks like this:

```
Limit  (cost=20368.26..20368.31 rows=20 width=751) (actual time=276.006..276.101 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=20368.26..20376.91 rows=3459 width=751) (actual time=276.001..276.035 rows=20 loops=1)
        Sort Key: article_date_added, (ts_rank(search_vector, to_tsquery('snowden|obama|nsa'::text)))
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 42kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on articles  (cost=1136.19..20276.22 rows=3459 width=751) (actual time=22.735..273.558 rows=600 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (search_vector @@ '( ''snowden'' | ''obama'' ) | ''nsa'''::tsquery)
              Filter: (ts_rank(search_vector, to_tsquery('snowden|obama|nsa'::text)) > 0.045::double precision)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on article_search_vector_index  (cost=0.00..1135.33 rows=10377 width=0) (actual time=20.512..20.512 rows=9392 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (search_vector @@ '( ''snowden'' | ''obama'' ) | ''nsa'''::tsquery)
Total runtime: 276.674 ms
```

The index that is being used is GIN because I care more about the search and the update. Some of the problems I notice with this query is the more '|' I add, the slower it gets. What would be some ways that I could optimize this query to still get decent results with speed?

Answer (score 1):

The bigger problem is the:

```
ORDER BY article_date_added DESC, rank DESC
```

It makes the planner consider a bunch of applicable rows based on full text, and it then ends up resorting them. If you `ORDER BY rank DESC` instead, you should get better results. (The default order in this case is by `rank DESC`.)

For the additional `|` decreasing performance, it's because each additional word/subquery is fetched separately as part of the bitmap index scan. The more rows qualify, the more will be fetched and considered for the top-n sort. It's perfectly normal.

Comment: The order by date is required because date order is important. Is there something else I should be using besides the | operator?

Comment: The `|` is correct if you really mean it to be: search for all articles in haystack that boasts either of needle or dart or spike or stick. Think of the index as leading pg to explore this or that part of the haystack to find relevant articles. The wider the search, the more parts of the haystack you explore, and the more valid rows qualify. And you then need to sort them, without an index at your disposal...